# Text alignment design and icons on buttons with css

Tags: css, ionic-framework, css-position

I need help in what it says, I'm designing these buttons, but they do not look with an order, I attach the image.

[image]

Well what I want is something like this (as you see in the picture everything is ordered):

[image]

```
page-home {
    p {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
    }
    .body {
        background-color: #FFEB3B;
    }
    .botones {
        vertical-align: text-bottom;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
}
```

Code HTML in IONIC

```
<ion-content padding class="body" align="center">
    <img src="../../assets/logito.png" class="imagen">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='logo-facebook'></ion-icon>
        Registro via Facebook
      </button>
    <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start color="secondary" class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='person-add'></ion-icon>
        Servicio Particular
      </button>
    <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start color="dark" class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='briefcase'></ion-icon>
        Servicio Corporativo
      </button>
    <br>
    <p>¿Eres nuevo? <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">REGISTRATE AHORA</a></p>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

I used a flexbox for the container and centered the content in the middle. Furthermore, the buttons got additional styling.

Since I'm not familiar with ion, you may have to rewrite the CSS selectors.

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.body {
  background-color: #FFEB3B;
}

.botones {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60px;
}

.botones:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.botones[color="secondary"] {
  background: blue;
}

.botones[color="dark"] {
  background: red;
}

ion-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding class="body" align="center">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" class="imagen">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='logo-facebook'></ion-icon>
        Registro via Facebook
      </button>
  <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start color="secondary" class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='person-add'></ion-icon>
        Servicio Particular
      </button>
  <button ion-button item-end round full icon-start color="dark" class="botones">
        <ion-icon name='briefcase'></ion-icon>
        Servicio Corporativo
      </button>
  <br>
  <p>¿Eres nuevo? <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">REGISTRATE AHORA</a></p>
</ion-content>
```